# No hint path defined for [mail] Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-8

In my Laravel Project i am trying to use Email sender and i use Mailable and a Job in a queue and that is working fine, but now i am trying to send a email using markdown and for some reason is not working bcs of this error: "No hint path defined for [mail]"

in Mailable:

```
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.orders.shipped',['url'=>'www.google.com']);
    }
}
```

and this is blade view, its the default example of Laravel docs:

```
@component('mail::message')
# Introduction

The body of your message.

@component('mail::button', ['url' => $url])
Button Text
@endcomponent

Thanks,<br>
@endcomponent
```

I need to pass a url that is gonna be a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have try this script it is working fine may be it is the issue of cache you can try this command

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: I dont know why but somehow it started  working with out me changing nothing xD but ty for help